# Connect to postgresql server on amazon ec2 (Linux AMI) from PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I started an amazon ec2 instance (Linux AMI) , and installed postgresql 9.2.15 over it. I then went to the Security Group: mygroup-1 and opened the 5432 TCP Port:

```
Ports   Protocol    Source      mygroup-1
80      tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
5432    tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
22      tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
3389    tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
443     tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
```

I have created a database and user. 
My **/var/lib/pgsql9/data/pg_hba.conf** looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

and **/var/lib/pgsql9/data/postgresql.conf** looks like this:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

from the local computer, I have successfully connected to the ec2 postgresql using pgAdmin 3 program with connection information:

```
host: Public IP of EC2 running
port: 5432 
username: my-postgresql-user
password: my-postgresql-pass
```

But when I try to connect to postgresql from my website using PHP (my website placed in the path **/var/www/html/mysite**), it can't connect.
My code:

```
$host = "Public IP of EC2 running";
$port = "5432";
$name = "my-postgresql-database";
$user = "my-postgresql-user";
$pass = "my-postgresql-pass";

$connstr = "host=$host port=$port dbname=$database_name user=$user password=$pass";
pg_connect($connstr);
```

when I run on local computer, it is connected ok, but when uploaded to **/var/www/html/mysite**, it can't connect to database.

I tried replacing the variables $host = "localhost" or "Public DNS of EC2 running" but still can't connect.

Please help

Comment: _it can't connect_ with what error message?

Comment: i fixed it, thanks :D

Comment: Hey Sonzero, I'm having the same problem right now, how did you fix it?